# Get numpy 2D array from user input

Tags: python, numpy, user-input

I am trying to get a numpy two-dimensional array from user input except it does not work properly as input() returns a 'str' type while the numpy array() method expects a tuple:

```
import numpy as N

def main():
    A = input()       # the user is expected to enter a 2D array like [[1,2],[3,4]] for example
    A = N.array(A)    # since A is a 'str' A
    print(A.shape)    # output is '()' instead of '(2, 2)' showing the previous instruction didn't work as expected

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

So my question would be: How can I turn the input string into a tuple so that the array() method properly turns the input into a numpy 2D array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to manually iterate through the string and get the numbers out in tuple form to create the array.

Answer (score 2):

The following interactive session worked fine in my case:

```
>>> A = input()
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> 
>>> A
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> type(A)
<type 'list'>
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.array(A)
array([[1, 2],
      [3, 4]])
>>>
```

Are you entering the data wrapped in quotes, i.e.:

```
>>> A = input()
"[[1, 2], [3, 4]]"
>>> A
'[[1, 2], [3, 4]]'
>>> type(A)
<type 'str'>
```

As that's the only reason I can think of for your code to fail.  Input does not return a string unless the user types one in; it is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())` in your case.

Comment: "Input does not return a string unless the user types one in": not true in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, it's a long time since I've used anything `input()` related.

Answer (score 2):

I think the code is correct you need to change the way you input data. Please look at following code snippet

```
>>> import numpy as N
>>> A = input()
((1,2),(3,4))
>>> type(A[0][0])
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 2):

> `Brett Lempereur` and `Sidharth Shah`'s answers is just for Python2 because input() in Python3 will return `str` by default.

In Python3, you would also need to use `ast` to eval string input to list.

```
>>> import ast
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrixStr = input()
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> type(matrixStr)
str
>>> matrixList = ast.literal_eval(matrixStr)
>>> type(matrixList)
list
>>> matrix = np.array(matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply you can just do this:

```
import numpy

def array_input():
    a = eval(input('Enter list: '))
    b = numpy.array(a)
return b
print(array_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[int(x) for x in input(f"Enter the value{[i]}:").split()] for i in range(3)])

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Numpy 2D array user defined input**

```
# Importing the NumPy library for numerical computations
import numpy as np

lis = []  # Initializing an empty list to store user input values

# Looping three times to get input for three different values
for i in range(3):
    # Prompting the user to enter a value and splitting it into separate values
    # based on the current iteration index i
    user_input = input(f"Enter the value {[i]}:").split()

    # Appending the entered values to the list
    lis.append(user_input)

    # Converting the list of entered values to a NumPy array with integer data type
    arr = np.array(lis, dtype=int)

print(arr)  # Printing the final NumPy array containing the entered values
```

Comment: It may be a great answer but without an explanation of how you arrived at it, it may just turn out to not be useful to others

Answer (score -1):

to get an integer input you have to pass input() within int()
like...

```
A=int(input())
type(A)
>>>int
```